# Angular2 ngClass not working

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to add a class with condition but it is not working

```
    <tr *ngFor="let time of times; let i = index">
        <td [ngClass]="{'red-time':checkInvalid(time['Proles Arrive'])}">{{time['Proles Arrive']}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is in my HTML

```
  checkInvalid(entry: string){ 
console.log("This is the entry:"  + entry);
    return entry === 'Invalid Entry';
  }
```

But the class is never added, even though when i log the entry it says "Invalid Entry"

Even when i use "[ngClass]="{'red-time':true}" its still not adding the class.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: could you show us an example of your `times` array?

Comment: What happens when you replace `checkInvalid(time['Proles Arrive'])` with the value you expect it to return?

Comment: The way I look at it it should be working unless there is something wrong with that array

Comment: Even when i use "[ngClass]="{'red-time':true}" its still not adding the class.

Comment: can you reproduce it ?

Comment: have you include 'CommonModule' in your AppModule ??

Comment: import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

Comment: @BrajendraSwain Why would i import it, i am not using it anywhere?

Comment: actually ngClass directive is part of CommonModule, so to make ngClass to work you need to add CommonModule in the import of Appmodule . did you get it?

Comment: the code seems ok, create a plunker otherwise you won't get any answers

Answer (score 0):

change the condition as follows

```
<td [ngClass]="{'red-time':checkInvalid(time['Proles Arrive'])==true}">{{time['Proles Arrive']}}</td>
```

Comment: What about this one.  [ngClass]="checkInvalid(time['Proles Arrive'])==true?'red-time':'green'". green is added as else condition class. if you dont want you can put an empty string ' '

Comment: check with false condition also.  checkInvalid(time['Proles Arrive'])=='false'